# How to count all npm packages used in the monorepo project?

Tags: npm, nlp, monorepo, pnpm

The current project is an older monorepo project, which uses yarn to manage dependency packages, and many subprojects use phantom dependencies. At present, the project is gradually migrating to pnpm, but there is a problem that each subproject uses many npm packages that are not in its own package.json. However, there are dozens of such sub-projects, and manual statistics are a very heavy workload. Is there any good tool that can help me find out all the npm packages that each sub-project depends on through text analysis? In this way, I can find all missing dependencies by comparing the subproject's package.json and add them to the subproject's package.json.

There is currently no good idea to solve this problem. In the search tool, if there is no such tool, consider using python to write a new one.